# how to create a session in PHP and head to different urls based on condition code

Tags: php

I am trying to create a session to check if a user is loged in, if a user has logged I want to display the index page otherwise I want to redirect them to the login page...I don't know if am doing it right but it's giving me an error saying no such file or directory exists..
Here is my code

```
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["IsLog"] ;
 if($_SESSION['IsLog']= false){
  header("Location: login.php") ;  
 }
 else {
 header("Location: index.php");
 }
```

Comment: do both of those files exist? in the root document folder of your app?

Comment: also as mentioned by piotr below, your condition validation needs 2 equal signs like this `==`.

Comment: Yes the pages exist and thanks for the correction but ot still cant see the link

Comment: provide a snapshot of your directory structure maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your condition. Use comparison operator like that:

```
if($_SESSION['IsLog'] == false){
```